# Xcode 4: debugging does not highlight current line in source code

Tags: debugging, breakpoints, xcode

I just reinstalled Xcode 4 from the App Store, but still the same issue:

When the debugger hits a break point the program stops and shows the stack trace. However, the line in the source code is not highlighted.

I tried clicking on various entries in the stack trace and stepped through the code - no highlighting.

**EDIT:**

<strike>I think I found the reason (but not solution yet):</strike> I have organized the source files into sub-directories. Each sub-directory is mapped to a group in Xcode. I bet Xcode checks only the project directory for source files not sub-directories.

My layout:

```
./Project Dir
   Classes/
      Group1/
        Class.m
      Group2/
        AnotherClass.m 
      ...
```

**EDIT 2:**

I just noticed that the debugger *does* highlight the line in `main.m`, but not in any other source file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found it. Culprit was this line in the source file:

```
#line __LINE__ "MainController.m"
```

Turns out that this confuses Xcode and I assume because of that Xcode won't find the file anymore to highlight the current line of a breakpoint.

The purpose of the preprocessor definition was to shorten log statements, which would contain the full path to the file in log statements when using the `__FILE__` macro.

Answer (score 0):

You can click on the sign in order to hight the line:
[image]

click

[image]

Comment: No, I am talking about the debugger not stopping at breakpoints (not compile warnings). Is it possible that the source information is not compiled into the binary? It used to work just fine in Xcode 3.2